# How to set a theme for Windows XP to use before a use logs in?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, themes

If Windows XP "welcome screen" is disabled (manually or by joining a domain) an ordinary window is used to log-in (like it was in Windows 2000). This window is styled with default Windows XP "Luna" theme (blue window title, etc). All theme customizations (including turning them off at all to use plain Win2000/98 window style) are normally applied after a user logs-in.

How can I alter this? I'd like either to turn off visual styles at all or to apply "Zune" styling to BEFORE a user logs in (and it'd be good to use the same settings as default for new users created).

Comment: WindowsBlinds maybe? Or add "/noguiboot" param to boot.ini for the normal win. start (if no boot.ini, start sysdm.cpl and change advanced -> startup/recovery). If I remember right that 'welcome screen' is hardcoded somewhere and not that easy to alter/remove it without damaging the OS.

Comment: If you disable the Themes service, those settings should apply to the Logon screen